# Can a hacker change final variable in my android app?

Tags: java, android

I have a final static int in my android app. Is a hacker able to change it's value **without** deobfuscating my application? Maybe with memory manipulation? And if there is a root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Obfuscation will make it harder to do, but does not provide any real security.
2. Changing a final static in Java is not impossible (through reflection for instance)
3. Being able to perform memory manipulation and being root will make a hack you think about rather easy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you can easily modify a `.class` file in the JAR.
Obfuscation just makes it harder to figure out which field to modify.

You can never trust anything that runs on an attacker's device.